# My For loop is only going through once. (I'm using Python)

Tags: python, function, for-loop

I am using Python and I have a for loop as shown below.

```
def calculateTrajectories(masses, positions, velocities, T, dt):

    #create lists for where we want to know positions, velocities at some time and convert them to np arrays
    current_positions = []
    new_positions = np.array(current_positions)
    current_velocities = []
    new_velocities = np.array(current_velocities)

    #call updateParticles function to get new positions, velocities at each step
        #loop starts at 0, ends at T, has step value of dt
    for i in range(0, int(T), int(dt)):
        #show all the time steps in the total time range
        steps = np.array(i)

        #call updateParticles
        Positions, Velocities = updateParticles(masses, positions, velocities, dt)[i]

        #assign the position and velocity results to their respective lists to get turned into arrays
        current_positions.append(Positions)
        current_velocities.append(Velocities)

        return steps, current_positions, current_velocities

    return steps, new_positions, new_velocities
```

I'm trying to use this function with the for loop to do this calculation which is supposed to yield 3 arrays called, steps, new_positions, new_velocities.

```
T4 = 8.64e7
dt4 = 8640
masses = [1.989e30, 5.972e24]
positions = [(-448794, 0.0, 0.0),(1.4959742e11, 0.0, 0.0)]
velocities = [(0.0, -8.94e02, 0.0),(0.0, 2.98e4, 0.0)]

calculation4 = calculateTrajectories(masses, positions, velocities, T4, dt4)
print(calculation4)
```

And this is what I get from this.

```
(0, [array([ -448793.33565708, -7724160.        ,        0.        ])], [array([1.49597199e+11, 2.57472000e+08, 0.00000000e+00])])
```

The updateParticles is another function, but I've checked and the problem does not have to do with that, it is definitely with the function I'm trying to make here called calculateTrajectories. I don't understand why my loop is only going through once, when I gave it a range of values to go through. 
Also, in the range() of the for loop, I had to make the stop and step values integers using int() because I got a type error if I left them, since a float couldn't be interpreted as an integer.

How can i fix my loop so that it goes through as many times as the range function asks it to?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: You have `return` is inside the loop. You return from the function after the first iteration.

Comment: Mark Meyer is Correct. Remove the return from the inner loop and check for the output of the code. Probably you add the contents of the loop into another variable and that variable will be the one you will return from the function

Answer (score 0):

Since you include a `return` inside the `for` loop, your defined function will complete during the first time through.

You're probably going to want to take that `return` out entirely, and move the `new_positions` and `new_velocities` below your loop.